# Redux combineReducer returns default state for reducer not called in action

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm new to react redux, so I think I'm just missing something basic.

I have three reducers, two to handle orders that update in the store as arrays, and one that shows the status of a web socket connection I'm using to receive orders from the server.

```js
// reducers.js

import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import { ADD_POS_ORDER, ADD_MOBILE_ORDER, UPDATE_WS_STATUS, wsStatuses } from '../actions/actions'
const { UNINITIALIZED } = wsStatuses

const posOrders = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_POS_ORDER:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: action.order.id,
          status: action.order.status,
          name: action.order.name,
          pickupNum: action.order.pickupNum
        }
      ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const mobileOrders = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_MOBILE_ORDER:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: action.order.id,
          status: action.order.status,
          name: action.order.name,
          pickupNum: action.order.pickupNum
        }
      ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const wsStatus = (state = UNINITIALIZED, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_WS_STATUS:
      return action.status
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const displayApp = combineReducers({
  posOrders,
  mobileOrders,
  wsStatus
})

export default displayApp
```

When I connect to the socket, I dispatch an action to update wsStatus and the action is stored as 'CONNECTED'.

When I follow with an order with the posOrders reducer, the wsStatus is reset to its default, 'UNINITIALIZED'.

What I am struggling to understand is why wsStatus is not using the previous state of 'CONNECTED', but instead returning default.

```js
// actions.js

export const UPDATE_WS_STATUS = 'UPDATE_WS_STATUS'

export const wsStatuses = {
  UNINITIALIZED: 'UNINITIALIZED',
  CONNECTING: 'CONNECTING',
  CONNECTED: 'CONNECTED',
  DISCONNECTED: 'DISCONNECTED'
}

export const ADD_POS_ORDER = 'ADD_POS_ORDER'
export const ADD_MOBILE_ORDER = 'ADD_MOBILE_ORDER'
export const  UPDATE_POS_ORDER = 'UPDATE_POS_ORDER'

export const setWsStatus = (status) => {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_WS_STATUS',
    status: status
  }
}

export const updateOrderQueue = (action, order) => {
  return {
    type: action,
    id: order.id,
    order: order,
    receivedAt: Date.now()
  }
}
```

Here's where I make the calls:

```js
// socketListeners.js

import { setWsStatus } from '../actions/actions'
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client'

export const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:3000/echo')

export default function (dispatch, setState) {
  socket.onopen = function () {
    dispatch(setWsStatus('CONNECTED'))
  }

  socket.onclose = function () {
    dispatch(setWsStatus('DISCONNECTED'))
  }
}
```

```js
// orders container

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { socket } from '../helpers/socketListeners'

import { updateOrderQueue, setWsStatus } from '../actions/actions'
import PosOrder from '../components/queue/PosOrder'

class PosOrderList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props

    socket.onmessage = function(e) {
      // convert order info to object
      let parsedOrder = JSON.parse(e.data)
      let action = parsedOrder.action
      let order = parsedOrder.order

      dispatch(updateOrderQueue(action, order))
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { updateOrderQueue } = this.props
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.posOrders.map(posOrder =>
          <PosOrder
            key={posOrder.id}
            {...posOrder}
          />
        )}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

PosOrderList.propTypes = {
  posOrders: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.hash,
    status: PropTypes.string,
    name: PropTypes.string,
    pickupNum: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string])
  }))
}

// send data to component props
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    posOrders: state.posOrders,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PosOrderList)
```

```js
// store

const store = configureStore(initialState)

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStore(
    displayApp,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(
      createLogger({
        stateTransformer: state => state.toJS()
      }),
      thunk,
      // socketMiddleware
    )
  )
}

addSocketListeners(store.dispatch, store.getState)
```

Lastly, the store logs here: [redux store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoiSt.png)

Any and all help on this would be very appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compose your reducer with combineReducers, for each dispatched action, all subreducers get invoked, since every reducer gets a chance to respond to every action.

Therefore, all state gets initialized after the first action is dispatched.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I'm stuck on is why the state is getting 're-initialized' for wsStatus on the second action.

Comment: One completely dumb question, are you sure you have just one store in your app and not two? Fishy thing in your store file is that you export store creation function but you also create one store but you do not export it. So i do not see how would you use that store elsewhere. But this local store gets connected to socket create and close events.

Comment: I don't believe I've created two stores. addSocketListeners is simply passing the dispatch function of the store to the web socket. Can you further elaborate how I'm creating a local store? I followed this ws setup, for reference: https://community.risingstack.com/handling-outside-events-with-the-redux-listener-pattern/

Comment: Ok, in store.js line 3 you create store, but you do not export it. In line 19 you wire this store to socket events. But since you have not exported this store, I do not see how would you use it elsewhere. Especially in your <Provider store={mystore}> component usually found somewhere in top of the hierarchy. Since you needed some store there, I guess you have called fnction configureStore() which you did export from store.js - hence creating second store. First store is wired to ws create and close and second pretty much to everything else.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I understand now, and that solves it! I moved addSocketListeners to where I declare my Provider component and all is well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your reducers are working fine https://jsfiddle.net/on8v2z8j/1/

```
var store = Redux.createStore(displayApp);
store.subscribe(render);
store.dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_WS_STATUS',status:'CONNECTED'});
store.dispatch({type: 'ADD_POS_ORDER',id:'id'});
store.dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_WS_STATUS',status:'DISCONNECTED'});
```

Comment: thanks for looking at this -- if you don't mind, can you explain why wsStatus is reverting to 'INITIALIZED' here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoiSt.png [I've updated the image with a log to better illustrate what I'm confused about]

Comment: The part where you initialize the store with the combined reducer is missing in you given example. According to the way I have done it 
    var store = Redux.createStore(displayApp);
the state is wsStatus is not getting reinitialized for the second action.

Comment: Added the store config. But I'm still unsure how the affects the wsStatus